# Use sharepoint workflow to retrieve data from Azure App

Tags: authentication, azure, office365, sharepoint-workflow, azure-active-directory

I'm using Office 365 and Windows Azure. I need to create an App on Azure that will require authentication and will be accessible for Sharepoint workflows.

I created simple ASP.NET app that uses Azure Active Directory for single sign-on (according to this steps: http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory )
Then I created workflow on Sharepoint, that calls this App and retrieves response content. Unfortunately it turns out that instead of website content it returns login page.

My question is how to make the connection between Sharepoint Workflow and Azure App, so that the App would require to log in for users, but would be accessible for the Sharepoint Workflows?

Sorry for my poor explanation, but I'm very new in this topic.

Comment: First question is are both O365/Sharepoint and the ASP.NET app authenticating against the same Azure directory?

Comment: Yes. When I log into the Sharepoint, I can access to Azure without logging in and other way around.